# What enemies carry plasma rifles?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I killed a thin man, and it said "thin man plasma rifle" exploded. So I captured the next one, and only got a light plasma from it. Mutons always seem to drop plasma rifles, but what other enemies do? And are there any enemies that drop weapons other than the plasma rifle, light plasma rifle, and pistol? e.g. heavy plasma, plasma sniper, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weapon which can be obtained depends on the enemy type. There is only one enemy type which can appear with two different weapons: Mutons (the normal version, not the Elite or Berserker variant) carry Light Plasma Rifles in the first month where they appear and are then upgraded to Plasma Rifles a month later.

- **Plasma Pistol:** Sectoid, Sectoid Commander
- **Light Plasma Rifle:** Thin Man, Muton (before upgrade), Floater
- **Plasma Rifle:** Muton (after upgrade), Heavy Floater
- **Heavy Plasma:** Muton Elite

The only plasma-tier weapons which must be built are the Plasma Sniper and the Alloy Gun (plasma tier shotgun).